# not able to save the state in cookie

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-cookie

I have a simple use case where I change the background color of the li element when the user selects a particular tab. What I want is the state of the background color is maintained even if the page is refreshed.

I have been trying to do this through jquery cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie but it doesn't seem to work.

I am doing this using cofeescript and here is my code :-

```
 jQuery ->
    $('.left-vertical-menu-elements li a').click ->
        $.cookie('lastclicked', @id)
        $(@).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')

        if($.cookie('lastclicked', @id))
            $(@).closest('li'.addClass('active'))
            $.cookie('lastclicked', null)
```

Html :-

```
%ul
            %li{:class => "active"}=link_to "Games Playing", "#",:id =>"playing-link "
            %li=link_to "Games Played", "#",:id =>"played-link"
            %li=link_to "Followers", "#",:id =>"followers-link"
            %li=link_to "Following", "#",:id =>"following-link"
            %li=link_to "References", "#",:id =>"refrences-link"
            %li=link_to "Notifications", "#",:id =>"notifications-link"
```

I have added `alert($.cookie('lastclicked'))` to see if the cookie is storing the id of last clicked element and this seems to give the right result.`

I have included the `jquery.cookie.js` file in my application but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few bugs.

1. Using braces on a `if` statement in CoffeeScript is a syntax error.
2. Saying `if('lastclicked')` is pointless, a string is always true.
3. `$.cookie('lastclicked')` returns a string and strings and you can't treat a string like a jQuery object.

I think you want something more like this:

```
jQuery ->
    $('.left-vertical-menu-elements li a').click ->
        $.cookie('lastclicked', @id)
        $(@).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
```

I've also switched your `this` to `@` since `@` is more idiomatic in CoffeeScript.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistakes, but it does not seem to work once the page is refreshed

Comment: how do I persist with the state when the page is refreshed ? I have made the changes as per your points but it doesn't seem to persist

Comment: @DevR: Have you tried giving it an `expires` option? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#usage

Comment: I want it to expire as soon as another link is clicked because these links take you to a different page where the sidebar remains, so I don't want to hard code the expires value. I will update the jquery code which I am using now, please have a look at it

Comment: @DevR: `$.cookie('lastclicked', @id)` sets the cookie, `$.cookie('lastclicked')` gets the cookie. You could clear the cookie when loading these other pages or maybe you don't even need a cookie for this, maybe `window.lastclicked` would do.

Comment: currently the active class is on games playing link when I select a link (say notifications) the page will refresh and I want the active class to be on notifications when the page refreshes as that was the link which I had selected

Comment: Why do you need a cookie for that at all? The page knows what page it is when it is rendered, doesn't it?

Comment: but the sidebar where I have placed my vertical menu item is being rendered again, and I want to keep the class active (which highlights the selection which led to page refresh) there.